# Display D3 Tree Layout in Linear Format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following the [D3 Collapsible Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) guide and am trying to change the layout of the tree from

[image]

To a linear format, where the 'root' node is the left-most node on the tree
 [image]

I don't know much about D3 just yet but I assume the `d3.diagonal()` function along with the nodes x & y parameters control the lines and node position. Any input or guides on this that would point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you switch to the linear format, do you use just one branch of the tree?

Comment: You don't need a layout for this. Just arrange the nodes in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
self.diagonal = d3.svg.line().interpolate('step')
    .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function (d) { return d.y; });
```

And then use the generator like this:

```
link.enter().append('svg:path', 'g')
    .duration(self.duration)
    .attr('d', function (d) {
        return self.diagonal([{
            y: d.source.x,
            x: d.source.y
        }, {
            y: d.target.x,
            x: d.target.y
        }]);
    });
```